# How to publish all versions of an item to Web DB (Sitecore 8.0+)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

**The end result**:
After publishing an item, all versions will be visible in the WEB DB, instead of the default behaviour of only having the latest item version.

I'm using Sitecore 8.2.170407

After reading [this](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_development_team/posts/multiple-item-versions-in-web-database) article, I tried to do several things:

- Remove both `RemoveOtherVersions` and `PublishTestingVersions` processors by doing a `<patch:delete />`. That did not work
- Add my own patch file, which inherits `Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishVersion.Processors.RemoveOtherVersions` and hides/overrides the base `Process` method. The new method will do nothing.
  [Image of patch class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGyZ8.png) and [Image of patch config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVPyt.png)
  That didn't work either.
- Tried removing the whole `<publishVersion>` pipeline, but that gave an exception when trying to publish an item.

I've not been able to find a solutions anywhere else. I know a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887245/how-to-publish-multiple-versions-of-content-item-to-delivery-web-database-in-s), but that was in Sitecore 6

Have any of you been in the same situation before? How did you solve the issue?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve? It seems you have chosen to solve the problem with all versions in the web DB, but that doesn't work. There may be another way to solve the problem... What are you attempting to do?

Comment: You are correct about the problem I'm trying to solve.
My case is simply:
I have 3 versions of an item. I publish the item, and all 3 versions will be visible in the web DB.

Comment: Sorry Casper, I meant, WHY are you needing 3 versions in the web DB? There may be another way to meet the WHY without needing 3 versions.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jay. I appreciate your time.
Our customer wants to have the opportunity to create content before hand, meaning they can create content for, lets say, 1 month ahead. With Sitecore's _lifetime_ feature, they would set the start date and end date for a specific version. I would think that unless there are versions in WEB db, lifetimes wouldn't work. 

Do you suggest another way?

Comment: I take that back. I clearly didn't research this enough. Sorry for taking your time. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The linked answer you provide is still valid. Sitecore "web" database (any database which is a publishing target) stores one and only one version. To modify this, you're going to need to reinvent your own publishing process.

Comment: Thanks for answering back.

Would I need to reinvent the WHOLE publishing process or is it possible to only modify the `RemoveOtherVersions` process (which is what I tried to do without any luck)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, it seems what you want to use is standard Sitecore versioning with specified publish start dates to put up a particular version.

All of the versions would live in your master database, and you would regularly run publishes through the publishing agent or some other means in order to send the appropriate version to the web database on the correct date.

Your authors can preview what the page would look like on a particular date using the date picker in the preview mode.